# Non-empty zero-indexed vector V of N integers, returns the minimal positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in V

Tags: c++, c++11

Please help me in optimizing the code. Seems to be working fine for most of the result set, but performance wise its seems to be slow. How can I further optimize the code.
Assuming vector is v{1,3,6,4,1,2};

```
int solution(vector<int> &v) {
 std::vector<int> v2,v3;
 sort(begin(v),end(v));
 v.erase(unique(begin(v),end(v)),end(v)); 
 std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator,std::vector<int>::iterator> p1=  std::minmax_element(begin(v),end(v));
 int last_  = *p1.second;
 for(int i=0; i < last_; i++)
     v2.push_back(i);
 if(v2.size() ==0)
   return 1;

 set_symmetric_difference(begin(v),end(v),begin(v2),end(v2),std::back_inserter(v3));
 auto up=upper_bound(begin(v3),end(v3),0);
 return *up;

}
```

Comment: [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

First, you code modifies the original vector which may or not be desirable.

Next as usual, think algorithm before code optimization. Once vector is sorted, find first positive number. If it is not 1, 1 is the solution.

If you have found number 1 in the sorted vector, just move forward:

- if next number is number + 1, just iterate
- if next number is > number + 1, the solution is number + 1
- if you reach end of vector, the solution is last number in vector + 1

Cost: cost of the sort plus N in worst case, average N/2

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the following code allows to compute the answer in linear time, as opposed algorithms involving sorting. First notice that the answer is less than or equal `N+1`, where N is a size of V.
So let's create a vector of length `N+1` `vector<int> count(N+1)`, and iterate through all values in `V`, so for `v` in `V` such that `v<N+1` we increase `count[v]++`. Finally go through all values in `count` and return first non zero index greater than 0. If all are more than zero, return `N+1`.

```
int solution(vector<int> &V){
    int N = V.size();
    vector<int> count(N + 1, 0);
    for(auto i = V.begin(); i != V.end(); i++){
        If (*i <= N) count[*i]++;
    }
    //now just find minimum value which doesn't occur in V
    int answer = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++){
        answer++;
        if (count[i] == 0){
             break;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```